# Why does R say 'cannot compute exact p-values with ties' when I can do it with pen and paper?

Tags: r, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, permutation-test, order-statistics

Suppose I have two sets of three numbers: $x_1, x_2, x_3$ and $y_1, y_2, y_3$ and I want to test the Null hypothesis that they are drawn from the same distribution using the Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney test.

So what I would do with pen and paper is the following:

1. Compute the test statistic $W_{observed}$ for my sample
2. Make a list of all 20 ways of assigning the label '$x$' to three of my 6 numbers and '$y$' to the three others
3. Remember that under the Null hypothesis all 20 assignments in my list are equally likely
4. Compute the statistic $W$ for all of them.
5. Count how many of these $W$'s are at least as extreme (defined as 'far from the median of my list of 20 $W$-values') as the value $W_{observed}$ of step 1
6. Divide this number by 20
7. Interpret (with step 3 in mind) the outcome of step 6 as the probability under the Null-hypothesis (conditioned on observing these 6 numbers) that I would have observed a $W$-value at least as extreme as the one I did observe.
8. Remember that the probability described in step 7 is the definition of $p$-value
9. Conclude that, in step 6, I computed the $p$-value of my test
10. Feel pleased with myself because I did this computation 'exactly'

Alternatively, I can feed my six numbers in to R as `wilcox.test(c(x_1, x_2, x_3), c(y_1, y_2, y_3))`

Non-surprisingly, if all 6 numbers are distinct, both methods give the same answer, with R being slightly faster.

However, when some $x_i$ equals some $y_j$ and even when some $x_i$ equals some $x_j$ (this seems even more absurd to me, although I cannot quite pinpoint why) R will complain that it 'cannot compute exact $p$-values with ties.'

My question is why?

Obviously the problem cannot be in step 2 through 7 so it must be in step 1 or 8. Indeed I found an internet-source claiming that the test statistic does not exist in case of ties (supporting the thesis that the problem lies in step 1): because the statistic is defined as a sum of ranks, it becomes undefined when some of the number are equal, as well-defined ranks do no longer exist in that case.

However this argument is invalid because, and here I quote the R helpfile of `wilcox test`:

> R's value can also be computed as the number of all pairs (x[i], y[j]) for which y[j] is not greater than x[i], the most common definition of the Mann-Whitney test.

Indeed, with this definition we can compute $W$ whether there are ties or not. **So why does R still have trouble with computing $p$-values?**

(Side note: there is a strange irony in the above quote form the help file, in that, in case of ties, R does *not* use above definition, but instead computes $W$ as the number of all pairs (x[i], y[j]) for which y[j] is strictly smaller than x[i] plus *one half* of all pairs (x[i], y[j]) for which y[j] is equal to x[i]. However that seems irrelevant to my question since as long as we have a way of computing $W$ we can run through the 10 steps I wrote down to obtain an exact $p$-value.)

Comment: Wilcoxon test is a ranked test.  The questions is what happens when x1 = y1?  Depending on how you order this pair will effect the test statistic, thus warning message.

Comment: @Dave2e it seems pretty clear to me that x[i] = y[i] is an example of y[j] being not greater than x[i]. So if we believe the help file there is no need to make a choice of ordering on this pair

Comment: R does not have access to pen and paper :)

Comment: Trivial but also fundamental point; it's not R in totality or abstraction making this decision; it is code written by a particular person or particular people declining to support what you want it to do. And it's not just a matter of sample sizes of 3 or 6 but any sample size. If you're a programmer, it is often prudent not to support a calculation that is likely to be dubious or misleading. Any way, the point about R, or any other software, is that there is scope to write your own code if you want something different.

Comment: R also has packages that can compute the exact *p*-value.  Although I didn't investigate the algorithm.  `Y = c(1,2,3,4,5,1,6,7,8,9); Group = factor(c(rep("A",5), rep("B", 5))); library(exactRankTests); wilcox.exact(Y ~ Group, exact=TRUE); library(coin); wilcox_test(Y ~ Group, distribution = "exact")`

Comment: Without ties the distribution of $W$ depends only on sample sizes, so you can look up $p$-values in a pre-computed table. With ties you have to calculate (or simulate) the distribution for your particular samples. That might be to do with the reason the writers didn't bother to support calculation of exact distributions when there are ties.

Comment: I don't suppose they do in fact use table look-ups, but I'd imagine there's a more efficient algorithm available for the no-ties case than the brute force evaluation of the test statistic for each permutation.

Comment: Yes, I think that the comment by Scorchi is probably the answer. R has the distribution of the $W$-statistic built in as `dwilcox` but its fast computation assumes no ties. Doing the computation for the cases with ties probably takes longer.

Comment: Those exact functions in R get pretty slow if *n* is greater than, say, 100.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `wilcox.test` from the standard `stats` library is limited to cases without ties because it uses an algorithm from the function `pwilcox` that assumes that there are no ties.

This algorithm is not your pen and paper solution which would become computation intensive for larger sample sizes.

The algorithm in `pwilcox` is not computing all possibilities, and instead it has a function that counts the number of possibilities for the tail. E.g. if the statistic $U$ which has the range $0$ to $n_1n_2$, had a value close to $0$, say $U = 4$ then we only compute the number of permutation that result in $U = 1$, $U = 2$, $U = 3$ and $U = 4$. The computations are done with iterations. This is faster than making all potential permutations and compute the statistic for each of those permutations.

The documentation of the `wilcox.test` function mentions that there are functions in other packages that can compute the exact test for the cases with ties.

> 'wilcox_test' in package coin for exact, asymptotic and Monte Carlo conditional p-values, including in the presence of ties.

The c-code of the algorithm behind the `wilcox.test` can be viewed on GitHub here: https://github.com/SurajGupta/r-source/blob/master/src/nmath/wilcox.c

An interesting related article might be (although I haven't read it myself because it is behind a paywall):

Bergmann, Reinhard, John Ludbrook, and Will PJM Spooren. "Different outcomes of the Wilcoxon—Mann—Whitney test from different statistics packages." The American Statistician 54.1 (2000): 72-77.

Comment: The argument doesn't rely on knowing the probability of a tie under the null - can you elaborate?

Comment: @Scortchi-ReinstateMonica I have added an example.

Comment: Thanks! I find that formulation puzzling - wouldn't the probabilities of each permutation differ even when $X$ & $Y$ are from continuous uniform distributions having the same bounds? I'll have to think about it, but at any rate a sharp null of $X$ & $Y$'s having the same distribution is a common, & valid, formulation.

Comment: @Scortchi-ReinstateMonica my example is an extreme case since the potential permutations may also be limited when there are no ties. But whenever the population is large compared to the sample, then that problem disappears, yet the problem with the ties remains. The example illustrates that you can not assume that the sample is an illustration for *both* distributions, and that you can freely permute and assume equal probability for each case.

Comment: I'd have thought that also R's standard computation without ties is only valid for the F=G null hypothesis (both distributions are equal), and not for the more general one you indicate. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Scortchi-ReinstateMonica you are right the test assumes equality of distribution. In fact, if you don't have equality and the distributions have the same mean or $P(x<y) = P(y>x)$ then the results can be false. The reason that the r-function doesn't use the pen and paper solution is because it is computation intensive.